# Is it possible to complete Asphalt 8 Airborne without IAPs?

Tags: ios, android, asphalt-8

I love Asphalt 8. But I'm starting to realize it may be impossible to complete without spending an absurd amount of real money, or literal years playing.

To get all the stars, you must buy and max out every car. The in-game currency required to do this is insane. The calculations below were made with info from **[this wikia](http://asphalt.wikia.com/wiki/Vehicles_of_Asphalt_8)**.

- 53,419,450 credits *and* 187,400 tokens to purchase all cars
- the above amounts to  **$3,060 USD** to buy necessary credits/tokens
- 173,847,160 credits to fully upgrade every car
- or **$5,800 USD**
- Total, if you were to buy everything, **$8,860 USD**

Now, for time. If each race takes about 3 minutes, and on average you earn 3,600 credits, I calculate roughly 3,156 hrs, or 79 weeks (40hr week),  of pure race time, not including time in between races, tuning cars, time for eat/drink/bathroom/sleep, and this doesn't even account for earning the 187,000 tokens.

Given this data, are the game designers making it impossible to complete Asphalt 8 Airborne with reasonable effort/purchases?

Comment: I'm not sure what answer you want, given that you've provided all the hard numbers in your question.

Comment: @JamesGecko I don't know everything there is to know about the game. I'm honestly asking. Maybe there's something I missed where credits and tokens can be earned much faster.

Comment: Reading [credit farming thread on its Wikia](http://asphalt.wikia.com/wiki/Thread:4263), it seems it's possible to do it without IAP: ~5000 credits/min. Notable comment from there: "*The "ground rule" of farming is to always choose the quickest race with the best race rewards. After mastering the track, one can start gathering the various Medal Rewards (Perfect Runs and Near Misses + jumping every jump & playing in an active manner).*"

Comment: I've done the 5K/minute method, it's super boring to replay the same race over and over again, and still very slow.

Comment: Collections (free upgrades plus credit prizes) and events may help slightly. Daily prizes also are a nice help (ex: check in all 30 days in November and get a free Lamborghini Miura, worth 300000+ credits). The daily reward system was implemented AFTER this question was asked. In addition, new multiplayer rewards make it easier as well. You also get a car by spending $40 and $4,000 USD (I don't know if can be purchased in-game with credits, so it may actually be impossible).

Comment: Not to mention that they're constantly adding new cars that you have to be Top 25 or so to unlock, then purchasable with tokens. There's also limited-time only cars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is actually not possible to completely finish the game. That is not the goal of the game. You can, however, get rather far without spending any dollar. The most important thing is that you have fun, making progress is great too but not really necessary.

Comment: I think by "finish the game" OP meant unlock everything, which is possible.

Answer (score 1):

There is only 0.096% chance (by luck) that you can complete the game. It involves the blueprints of certain McLaren race car which you will require to enter season 10 and some credits to upgrade your any vehicle to max level so that you can race in season 9. This chance is calculated through car kits reward giving pattern, but according to me till season 9 you can get DEVEL SIXTEEN PROTOTYPE, giving you the most thrilling experience out of your 2.5 GB game and it is worth it.
Another thing, to save money you can look for some cars (for eg. chevrolet corvette C7 that provides you extra 16 star on winning while you dont need another chevrolet car), which gives you more stars per credit used.